# check if date argument is in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: shell-script, ksh, date

Is there a way to check if a date argument is in the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD)?

I got this from the web but it doesn't work for me:

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "2015-10-11" > /dev/null  2>&1
echo $?
```

I am expecting a `0` result but that's not the case. Can someone tell some another way?

Comment: why are you expecting false result?

Comment: if the result is `0` then, then command is true or correct any number other than `0` is invalid format.

Comment: Oh ok, now I start to see : did you read the comments of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731346/validate-date-format-in-a-shell-script#18731444)? I think this peace of code validate only if it is a possible date for (only) the format mm/dd/yyyy which is not your format

Comment: yes. I kinda modify it to suit my requirements but its not working either

Comment: Your command looks fine. When I try it, it behaves just as expected: `0` for valid dates and `1` for invalid ones.

Comment: @louggle, I mean, this code works only for checks on mm/dd/yyyy dates. And it does not check if format is correct, but if this is a valid date E.G.: 09/99/2013 in the format mm/dd/yyyy is not a valid date

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue either, that code sample prints 0 on my machine (`date` from GNU coreutils 8.13). What version do you have?

Answer (score 13):

This will check for the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD) in `bash` (with built-in regex match):

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
  then echo "Date $1 is in valid format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
  else echo "Date $1 is in an invalid format (not YYYY-MM-DD)"
fi
```

Run:

`./script.sh 2015-12-10`

Output:

`Date 2015-12-10 is in valid format (YYYY-MM-DD)`

It doesn't check if the date itself is valid, only the **format** (as stated in the question, "Check if a date argument is in the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD"))

If you need to check the date format *and* validate the date value, try something like:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && date -d "$1" >/dev/null
      then echo "Date $1 is valid and matches the format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
fi
```

This will discard invalid dates like 0000-88-77 that pass the regex matching.

(Credit goes to @glenn jackman for this suggestion.)

Comment: I would also use `if [[ ... ]] && date -d "$1" >/dev/null` to validate both the format and the actual value -- discard invalid dates like 9999-99-99 that pass the regex matching.

Comment: @glennjackman Agreed, edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: If you end up using `date` anyway, why not use the one-liner from the question?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Using `date` is not required to check the format. The format is checked with `bash` regex matching. Using date additionally validates the **value**, not **format**.

Comment: `date` is not required to check the format, but it **can** be used check it, so why write a custom regex for something which is already there?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev See my comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have not tagged an OS, and because you're using `ksh` I'm guessing you're probably not using Linux, and you *might* be using Solaris. The `date` command you give will work, but it's for GNU `date` where `-d` (or `--date`) is a GNU enhancement.

So the simple option is to use GNU `date`, you may need to install the GNU coreutils package, or you may already have it (check in `/usr/sfw/bin` on Solaris) it may already be available possibly as `gdate` or `gnudate`. This will properly validate the date in the YYYY-MM-DD format (unlike the regex examples elsewhere which will accept
2015-31-01)

You may instead be able to use the `touch` command in a similar and [more portable (POSIX)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) way

```
touch -c -d 2015-12-12T00:00:00 /tmp/does-not-exist
```

- use `-c` so that a file is not created
- append T00:00:00 to the date to make a valid time stamp

(However, if you are using Solaris not only do some versions lack `-d`, I have found some versions at least have a bug/misfeature where they do not validate and instead try to be smart, so "2015-02-29" becomes "2015-03-01" with no error, so you cannot use these versions for date validation.)

I prefer this way, it's robust and portable assuming you have `gawk` (or `mawk` instead, but traditional `nawk` lacks these time functions).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{
    split(ARGV[1],bb,/-/)
    tm=mktime( bb[1] " " bb[2] " " bb[3] " 00 00 00")
    tms=sprintf("%04i-%02i-%02i",bb[1],bb[2],bb[3])
    if (tms==strftime("%Y-%m-%d",tm)) exit 0
    exit 1
}
```

The above

- takes the first argument and splits in on the "-" character.
- `mktime()` to determine an epoch time stamp for the indicated YYYY-MM-DD
- `sprintf()` to normalise the YYYY-MM-DD (leading 0)
- `strftime()` to convert epoch time back to YYYY-MM-DD, and compare as a string

The reason for the extra convert and compare is to catch the case where questionable dates are reinterpreted by the C library `mktime()`, as is the case with glibc on linux (the same problem as with Solaris `touch` above).

Caring about the correct format of YYYY-MM-DD may or may not mean caring about the *validity* of the date (something `date` will do), and might even mean being able to eliminate [YYYY-DD-MM format dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_year-day-month_.28YDM.29). If you only wish to confirm the format is "date like", then a regular expression will suffice:

```
grep -qE "^[0-9]{4}-[01]?[0-9]-[0123]?[0-9]$"
grep -qE "^[12][0-9]{3}-(0?[1-9]|10|11|12)-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"
```

(On Solaris use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` not the default `grep`)
The first one will reject most bogus dates, the second one will reject almost all bogus dates. With `-q` there will be no output and you can use the return code as expected. Take care to anchor (`^...$`) or otherwise restrict the regular expression so that it does not simply match valid substring, e.g. 2015-12-12345

Comment: What if just `^[0-9]{4}-(0?[1-9]|10|11|12)-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$` to support years from 0000 to 9999 instead of just `1000-2999`?

Comment: Feel free, but there are increasingly many bear-traps as you travel back from 1970, so a robust (location aware) time library should be considered for anything better than "date like".

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn how to write a regular expression to validate that a date is in the correct format. yyyy-mm-dd

An easy method would be to do this on one line so that you can play around with the date and the regular expression and learn quickly.

I would use `echo` to produce the date, then `egrep` to apply the regular expression and indicate whether it finds a match or not. Look at the manual page for `egrep`, you will see there is a `-c` option which prints a count of matches, since you would send it only one date, the count would be either 0 or 1 depending on whether it found a match.

Here's your one liner to play with.

```
echo 0000-00-00 |egrep -c -e 'regular-expression-in-here'
```

insert regular expressions (you could start with the one [A.P](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/137752/a-p) gave you in their answer) to see how well it works. Change the date and see what it validates. Here's another one, slightly different.

`[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]`

Comment: Using a regular expression to parse dates is not a good idea. For one, determination of "valid" dates is non-trivial in regular expressions -- ie. determination that 2015-02-31 is not valid, but 2015-03-31 is.

Comment: I understand your point, the question is to validate the format not check whether a date is valid, I think this is a homework assignment, he asked for another way (than using date). :-]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare if `date` output for your date matches the original value:

```
d="2015-10-11"
if [ "`date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d $d 2>/dev/null`" = "$d" ]
then
  echo $d is a valid YYYY-MM-DD date
else
  echo $d is NOT a valid YYYY-MM-DD date
fi
```

Comment: I don't think you're **checking** the input format. You're **coercing** the format with `date`. The user can supply 20151011 as a value to "$d", and you won't know.

Comment: 20151011 is not a valid value (as defined in the question) and therefore it won't be validated. I'm not coercing, I'm checking the value explicitly with `=`

Comment: It won't be validated, but you won't know why. Maybe because of invalid **format** (not conforming to YYYY-MM-DD), maybe because of an invalid **value** (2015-02-31). You will not know. The OP's question was not about **value** validation, but of **format validation**. Regarding coercion, I meant `date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d $d`. This does coerce $d to the specified format.

Comment: The question about format vs. value being incorrect is quite philosophical. For example 2015-13-01 can be both incorrect format (YYYY-DD-MM) or incorrect value (there is no 13-th month). Not only my script will not know why validation failed, but it's simply impossible to know.